# Gray rectangle appearing in Google Maps when I place a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map in my Python/GAE webapp, and when I place the map by itself, without a pin, it displays correctly. However, when I have a marker places on it, a good chunk of the map is wiped out with a gray rectangle. [image]

Here is my JS code:

```
//Places a Google Map with a pin at the coordinates of the stopimap
 function initialize(lat, lng) {                                 
    var mapProp = {
       center:new google.maps.LatLng(37.761586,-122.4477),
       zoom:12,
       mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var point=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
    }); 
}//initialize
```

Comment: I think you should refer to this url https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/training/customizing/custom-markers

Comment: I got it working, it was some CSS tomfoolery that was the problem.